# Rails simple_form validations not validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple form, which is using a model (which doesn't have a DB table, but I don't think that that's relevant) and I can't seem to get the validations to test:

the form:

```
   = simple_form_for(@client_email, url: { action: "update" }, html: {class: "search_form",  method: :put }) do |f|
      = f.error_notification
      .input-row
        = f.input :oldDomain, :label => "Old Domain Name", input_html: {name: 'search_term'}, :required => true
        = f.input :newDomain, :label => "New domain name", :required => true
```

[there's also a submit button, etc]

(note that this also seems to allow submitting without either field entered)

in my model, I have:

```
class ClientEmail
  include Virtus.model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming


  attribute :newDomain, String
  attribute :oldDomain, String

  validates :newDomain, :format => { :with  => /\A([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/}
  validates :oldDomain, :format => { :with  => /\A([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/}

  validate :cannot_be_present

  def cannot_be_present
    newDomClients = Client.where("email like :foo", {:foo => "%#{newDomain}%"})
    if newDomClients.length > 0
      errors.add(:newDomain, "There cannot be any emails already in the database with the target domain" )
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to check the format, OR even go into the "cannot_be_present" validation. (I've added debug statements)

The "required" bits in the f.input lines are being used, because it has the "*" meaning that it's required. It just doesn't complain if it's not there...

Comment: have you tried using `attr_accessor :newDomain` and try to use snake_case instead of camelCase on those cases

Comment: I have tried attr_accessor, it didn't do anything. Where should I be using snake_case? on the old/new domains?

Comment: snake case on oldDomain --> old_domain... (in both the model and the view presumably...)